# What happens when I change the default return of __unicode__ method to pass multiples foreignkeys

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wondering, in terms of database efficiency, if I edit the return `__unicode__` method and do something like this:

```
class AnyModel(models.Model):
    a_field = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b_field = models.ForeignKey(B)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "A - B: %s - %s " % (self.a_field.a2.a3, self.b_field.b2.b3)
```

So, the `__unicode__` method will hit the foreign key's foreign key's foreign keys, get a string and then return it.

... **Is it too expensive?** What criteria should I follow? Is there any general advice I could use? Is it better not to write this kind of `__unicode__` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happening with this structure:

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return "A - B: %s - %s " % (self.a_field.a2.a3, self.b_field.b2.b3)
```

Hits :

```
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_a"."id", "core_a"."a2_id" FROM "core_a" WHERE "core_a"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (2,); args=(2,)
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_a2"."id", "core_a2"."a3_id" FROM "core_a2" WHERE "core_a2"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
(0.012) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_a3"."id" FROM "core_a3" WHERE "core_a3"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_b"."id", "core_b"."b2_id" FROM "core_b" WHERE "core_b"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_b2"."id", "core_b2"."b3_id" FROM "core_b2" WHERE "core_b2"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
(0.005) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_b3"."id" FROM "core_b3" WHERE "core_b3"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
```

But, if you do this,:

```
def __unicode__(self):
        a_relation = AnyModel.objects.select_related('a_field__a2__a3').get(pk=self.pk)
        b_relation = AnyModel.objects.select_related('b_field__b2__b3').get(pk=self.pk)
        return "A - B: %s - %s " % (a_relation.a_field.a2.a3, b_relation.b_field.b2.b3)
```

When execute the line :

```
a_relation = AnyModel.objects.select_related('a_field__a2__a3').get(pk=self.pk)
```

1 hit :

```
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_anymodel"."id", "core_anymodel"."a_field_id", "core_anymodel"."b_field_id", "core_a"."id", "core_a"."a2_id", "core_a2"."id", "core_a2"."a3_id", "core_a3"."id" FROM "core_anymodel" INNER JOIN "core_a" ON ( "core_anymodel"."a_field_id" = "core_a"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_a2" ON ( "core_a"."a2_id" = "core_a2"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_a3" ON ( "core_a2"."a3_id" = "core_a3"."id" ) WHERE "core_anymodel"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
```

and When execute the second line:

```
b_relation = AnyModel.objects.select_related('b_field__b2__b3').get(pk=self.pk)
```

+1 Hit:

```
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_anymodel"."id", "core_anymodel"."a_field_id", "core_anymodel"."b_field_id", "core_b"."id", "core_b"."b2_id", "core_b2"."id", "core_b2"."b3_id", "core_b3"."id" FROM "core_anymodel" INNER JOIN "core_b" ON ( "core_anymodel"."b_field_id" = "core_b"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_b2" ON ( "core_b"."b2_id" = "core_b2"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_b3" ON ( "core_b2"."b3_id" = "core_b3"."id" ) WHERE "core_anymodel"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
```

And when execute

```
return "A - B: %s - %s " % (self.a_field.a2.a3, self.b_field.b2.b3)
```

**Doesn't hit the database.**

.
**1 - Edit**

You can join this, to :

```
def __unicode__(self):
        relation = AnyModel.objects.select_related('a_field__a2__a3', 'b_field__b2__b3').get(pk=self.pk)
        return "A - B: %s - %s " % (relation.a_field.a2.a3, relation.b_field.b2.b3)
```

and will hit only once.

```
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT "core_anymodel"."id", "core_anymodel"."a_field_id", "core_anymodel"."b_field_id", "core_a"."id", "core_a"."a2_id", "core_a2"."id", "core_a2"."a3_id", "core_a3"."id", "core_b"."id", "core_b"."b2_id", "core_b2"."id", "core_b2"."b3_id", "core_b3"."id" FROM "core_anymodel" INNER JOIN "core_a" ON ( "core_anymodel"."a_field_id" = "core_a"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_a2" ON ( "core_a"."a2_id" = "core_a2"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_a3" ON ( "core_a2"."a3_id" = "core_a3"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_b" ON ( "core_anymodel"."b_field_id" = "core_b"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_b2" ON ( "core_b"."b2_id" = "core_b2"."id" ) INNER JOIN "core_b3" ON ( "core_b2"."b3_id" = "core_b3"."id" ) WHERE "core_anymodel"."id" = %s' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
```

Comment: Here u can see the documentation about the select_related,https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. I'll mark accept it. One extra question, do you think is it worth it to do the join and hit only once?

Comment: I prefer hit only once.